# Attach sequence to a column and start with 1000

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

Apply this sql script:

```
create table software (
  id                        bigint not null,
  name                      varchar(255),
  description               varchar(255),
  constraint pk_software primary key (id))
;

create sequence software_seq;
```

Then this one:

```
alter sequence software_seq start with 1000;;

insert into software (id, name, description) values (  1, 'Soft1', 'Description1');
```

Then **when insert new software** programatically (from java), got new software with **id = 24**

**Why not with 1001?** Since 'alter sequence **software_seq start with 1000**;'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few things wrong here.

First of all, just creating a sequence with a particular name doesn't attach it to the table and column that you want using it. You need to change `software.id` to use `software_seq` for default values:

```
alter table software alter column id set default nextval('software_seq');
```

and you'll want to change the [sequence's ownership](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) too (unless of course you're using the sequence in other places):

> `OWNED BY table_name.column_name`
>   `OWNED BY NONE`
>
> The `OWNED BY` option causes the sequence to be associated with a specific table column, such that if that column (or its whole table) is dropped, the sequence will be automatically dropped as well. If specified, this association replaces any previously specified association for the sequence. The specified table must have the same owner and be in the same schema as the sequence. Specifying `OWNED BY NONE` removes any existing association, making the sequence "free-standing".

So you should:

```
alter sequence software_seq owned by software.id;
```

Then when inserting, you'd either leave out the `id`:

```
insert into software (name, description) values ('...', '...');
```

or specify DEFAULT:

```
insert into software (id, name, description) values (default, '...', '...');
```

Your other problem is that `start with` doesn't do what you think it does:

> `start`
>
> The optional clause `START WITH` ***start*** changes the recorded start value of the sequence. This has no effect on the **current** sequence value; it simply sets the value that future `ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART` commands will use.

If you want the sequence to start at 1000 then you can:

```
alter sequence software_seq restart with 1000;
```

Alternatively, you could use [`setval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

```
select setval('software_seq', 1000);
```

Of course, you could also use [`bigserial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases). In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

So using `bigserial` as the `id` column type would set up all the sequence stuff for you. Then you'd set the starting value as before using `alter sequence` or `setval`.

Comment: About attaching: I think it is attached by default by name, since it works for that table after this sequence was defined.

Comment: And I need some ids to have predefined because I use some data (rows) in tests by.. id.

Comment: @ses: Is your Java stuff doing things behind your back? Things like attaching the sequence to the `software.id` default value? I'm not familiar with the Java side of things but someone has to be attaching the sequence to the table, PostgreSQL won't do it automatically unless you use one of the serial column types. If you don't want to use the sequence then just specify the `id` manually in the INSERT, just watch out that you stay below 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I got. If one wants to change the sequence, then he should use this syntax:

ALTER SEQUENCE sequenceName [ RESTART WITH long ] [ INCREMENT BY long ]

i.e. use 'RESTART' but not 'START'

I tested: then it really start with 1000 when inserting new value.